# C# Lambda Join with an OR condition

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Is it possible to translate this SQL statement into C# lambda syntax?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Table1_ID = t2.Table1_ID
    OR t1.Some_Other_Column = NULL
```

For the C# syntax I would do something like this:

```
context.Table1
    .Join(context.Table2,
        t1 => t1.Table1_ID,
        t2 => t2.Table1_ID,
        (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        // start listing out properties here:
        x.t1.first_column,
        x.t1.last_column,
        x.t2.first_column,
        // and so on
    }).ToList();
```

I'm just not sure how to include the condition: OR t1.Some_Other_Column = NULL
into the above statement.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to return all records from `Table2` when `Some_Other_Column is null`? IMHO I would `.Concat` two queries.

Comment: Side note: `t1.Some_Other_Column = NULL` will always return false, presumably you meant `t1.Some_Other_Column IS NULL`

Comment: @Charlieface sorry, but LINQ follows C# semantics for `null` comparisons not SQL. Providers like LINQ to entities will generate the SQL to match C# semantics (I took the SQL as exemplar).

Comment: @Richard I'm aware of that, but OP has a "SQL statement" to translate, and that is what I was referring to. I assume OP didn't actually mean that, and really had `IS NULL` in their SQL. As you say, in Linq it is different

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I meant IS NULL.  It was late and I wasn't using a SQL IDE when I wrote the example sql script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the `Join` LINQ operator as it only supports equality for the join expression.

You could do this via a where operation, how a LINQ provider translates this will depend on the provider:

```
source1.SelectMany(x => source2.Select(y => new { x, y })
       .Where(v => v.x.Prop1 = v.y.Prop1
                || v.x.Prop2 is null)
```